# Can I run command-line commands within a python script?

Tags: command-line, python, scripts

Sorry I'm kind of a noob at this:

Basically I've downloaded this package that deals with text files that is run from the terminal, but the command I need takes in two arguments. I also need to do this many times (5000+).

I need to get these arguments with a python script, and can loop it many times using python. So could I get the arguments within the python script, run the command-line line, and loop it? How?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be better off on http://stackoverflow.com because it is not specifically related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @confoosed -- You need to edit to add "I've downloaded this package `to my Ubuntu box`...". </halfserious>

Comment: Are you saying you need to have python actually execute built-in shell/bash functions?  That can be done (e.g., see V's popen example), but you could use some more details in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a fish...

```
import popen2, sys

def loopy_subprocess(arga, argb, iterations, command = 'echo'):
    for i in range(int(iterations)):
        p = popen2.Popen4((command, arga, argb))
        p.wait()
        print(p.fromchild.readlines())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        arga = sys.argv[1]
        argb = sys.argv[2]
        iterations = sys.argv[3]
    except:
        print("You didn't supply enough arguments\n"+\
              "Usage: python script.py arga argb iterations\n"+\
              "Warning - unsafe.  No input validation and doesn't account for spaces in arguments\n"+\
              "Optionally supply the command to be run as a final argument\n")
        quit()
    try:
        command = sys.argv[4]
        loopy_subprocess(arga, argb, iterations, command)
    except:
        loopy_subprocess(arga, argb, iterations)
```

Comment: @belacqua - I could have used call but it doesn't support wait.  i thought wait was necessary given that the want to run batches of 5000 (I also think threading is necessary, but the question doesn't merit a threading answer) blah blah blah.

Comment: Change the `popen2` calls to the `subprocess` module. `popen2` and family are deprecated in Python 2 and removed from Python 3. Don't use `quit()` or `exit()`, they are added by `site.py` at runtime and do not work in all circumstances. Use `sys.exit()` or raise a `SystemExit`. Bonuspoint for using something like `argparse`.

Comment: @Timo - feel free to edit the changes in... it won't bother me at all, and if it makes a better answer great.  i guess old habits die hard.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to access the command line arguments from within python and also do the loop within python. You could look into `sys.argv` from the `sys` module to access the command line arguments. If I recall correctly that should allow you to do something like:

```
python scriptname.py argument1 argument2
```

and then access the arguments within scriptname.py using

```
import sys
arg_1 = sys.argv[1]
arg_2 = sys.argv[2]
```

You could also develop a whole stack of commands easily with a tool like [cliff](https://cliff.readthedocs.org/en/latest) (Command Line Interface Formulation Framework) .